# How to Include or Autoload Class Files in Solarium for SOLR

Tags: php, solr, autoload, solarium

I'm Trying to include or autoload [Solarium](http://www.solarium-project.org/) for SOLR in PHP and I keep getting errors. I know I'm doing it incorrectly but I'm new to autoloading. I have the extension installed for php and that works. Here is the error I receive:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Solarium\Client' not found in /Users/...
```

Here is my php file with code I'm testing—I realize that there is no autoloading setup in my example, I'm new to autoloading confused at how to use it:

```
<?php

require(__DIR__.'/init.php');

// check solarium version available
echo 'Solarium library version: ' . Solarium\Client::VERSION . ' - ';
```

Comment: how did you install it? http://wiki.solarium-project.org/index.php/V3:Installation - I also reduced the code-example in your question because I guess more lines of code are not necessary to provde the fatal error, right? Please review.

Comment: Thanks Hakre. I was trying to use the supplied autoloader by including it directly but that wasn't working either. I downloaded the prepacked release from GitHub. The reason why I wasn't using Composer is because none of my extensions/packages use it, so it seemed like rather than have ANOTHER extension for this, to just use the supplied autoloader.

Comment: Using the suppied autoload should work but you need to set it up (which seems a bit of your issue here). Using composer does this for you. It's not wrong to use some package manager in my eyes, however following the documentation you should be able as well to checkout / download from github.  Is `init.php` the autoloader here?

Comment: @Hakre I don't believe that init.php is the autoloader. I think autoloader.php is the autoloader.

Comment: well you need to include the autoloader then I guess. I don't know that library in specific but either it ships with an autoloader it's own or you need to use a PSR-0 (or which standard it follows) one. But  most often those libraries have also an autoloader their own. Include it and you should be fine.

Comment: I have same problem. I never use Composer. I download it but when I install it I am asked to compile my php with --openssl but my PHP is already configured for my PC long time ago. I don't want to recompile it. I am using Win7. I find the autoload.php. How should I configure it? Just update the path of required php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to install Solarium is by using Composer. Solarium is available on Packagist. For more info see https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium